# Creating Modals with AngularJS with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an angular app using UI-Router where I am nesting several modal pop-up views within a state. For example, I have a state I've defined as setting-up:

```
$stateProvider.state('setting-up', {
    url: '/setting-up',
    templateUrl: 'partials/setting-up.html'
});
```

And then I have the modal views nested within that state:

```
//adapted from this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/
$stateProvider.state("setting-up.modal", {
  views:{
    "setting-up.modal": {
      templateUrl: "partials/modal.html"
    }
  },
  onEnter: ["$state", function($state) {
    $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 27) {
        $(document).off("keyup");
        $state.go("setting-up");
      }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".Modal-backdrop, .Modal-holder", function() {
      $state.go("setting-up");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".Modal-box, .Modal-box *", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  }],
  abstract: true
});

$stateProvider.state("setting-up.modal.1", {
  views:{
    "setting-up.modal": {
      templateUrl: "partials/setting-up.1.html"
    }
  }
});

$stateProvider.state("setting-up.modal.2", {
  views:{
    "setting-up.modal": {
      templateUrl: "partials/setting-up.2.html"
    }
  }
});
//etc.
```

Doing it longhand like this, it works fine. The problem is I have about 10 different modal views for multiple states that I have to repeat this same code for and so I would like to use a function to generate my modal views for each one.

So far I've created something like this:

```
var GenerateModal = function($state, $url) {
  $obj[$state + ".modal"] = {templateUrl: $url }
  return $obj;
};

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  $stateProvider.state("setting-up.modal.i", GenerateModal("setting-up.modal", "partials/setting-up.i.html" ););
}
```

Unfortunately, that's not working. Should I be doing something else or is it simply more straightforward to write it out longhand?

Comment: why dont use ui bootstrap?

Comment: yozawiratama is right. Just use ui-bootstrap modal.